# Can I ask a question with significant regional component?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering if I can ask a city specific question about bikes, and where they end up? ETC, why it's hard to recycle?

This is just an example.

Let me know

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly fine - we have existing tags that identify when a question is of regional bias.

IE there is a #London (because cycling is huge there) as well as #UK
There are some US State tags as well, #California
And we have country tags like #japan and #australia.

Curiously we have no tags for amsterdam, holland, dutch or netherlands despite the mass cycling population there.

WRT your example, recycling doesn't have to have a specifically local component.  Could be there are no smelters anywhere near you, so scrap is cut and packaged for recycling elsewhere.  This may make steel uneconomic to recycle.  Aluminium is always worth recycling unless its mixed with other metals.

I'd suggest avoiding shopping questions, like "what's the best/cheapest/fastest bike shop in livingtown ?"

Also questions around dated events would be off topic even if they're bike events, like "what's happening at Biketober 2017 ?" because that will be out of date after the event is over.

Comment: We need a #NewZealand or #kiwi tag given the disproportionate numbers of kiwis here.  :)